# What are the edge cases when using Object.prototype.toString?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tostring

So far I have relied on `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)` to distinguish between the different native object types in Javascript, arrays in particular.

If you subclass arrays, you get some strange behavior:

```
function Ctor() {}
Ctor.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
var x = new Ctor();
x.push(1);

Object.prototype.toString.call(x); // [object Object]
```

Probably this is documented in the ES5 specs (and no longer an issue in ES6), but I consider it a quirk of the current version of the language. I adapted my corresponding functions as follows:

```
function objTypeOf(deep, type) {
  return function _objTypeOf(x) {
    do {
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(x).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase() === type) return true;
      x = Object.getPrototypeOf(x);
    } while(deep && x !== null);

    return false;
  };
}

var arr = objTypeOf(false, "array"),
 arrP = objTypeOf(true, "array"); // array prototype

console.log(arr(x)); // false
console.log(arrP(x)); // true
```

`objTypeOf` checks the current object and the entire prototype chain until there is a type match. It accepts an object even if merely one of the prototypes matches the expected type. `objTypeOf` is not based on prototype identities, but on strings (lacking identity).

I wonder now if there are other edge cases when using `Object.prototype.toString`, that need special treatment?

Comment: Btw, if you are looking for a reliable array detection, you should just use `Array.isArray`.

Comment: @Bergi: But isn't `isArray` based on `Object.prototype.toString`?

Comment: It might work via the same mechanisms, but it's not based on it, no. `Array.isArray` is a native function, expresses your intent properly, is not a hack, and works as you need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your problem is not with `Object.prototype.toString`, but that you tried to [subclass arrays](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/). It just doesn't work, and `toString` correctly tells you that you failed to create an array. It's merely an object that has `Array.prototype` in its prototype chain (if that was what you cared for, use `instanceof Array`).

Regardless, to answer your title question:

> What are the edge cases when using Object.prototype.toString?

Host objects. Everything that is not a native JS object, despite looking like one, might return any [[Class]] value that you didn't expect. There are even known cases where callable objects do not report `Function`.

Comment: On the other hand `Array.prototype.toString` tells me, that it's an array. I call that quirky. To `instanceof`: I use this operator whenever there is only a single context, `toString`otherwise.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt: Nope, [`Array.prototype.toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2) doesn't tell you anything. It tries to call `this.join()`, which succeeds for your objects that inherit from `Array.prototype`, but there's nothing behind that.

Comment: That means `Array.prototype.toString` is just duck typing with `join`? Darn!

Comment: @IvenMarquardt: Yes, all Array methods use duck typing